# ping output statistics to file

Tags: bash, centos, ping, tee

```
[root@localhost ~]# while true; do timeout -s 2 1h ping 96.120.16.121 | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S |' | tee -a ping.log; done
```

easier to read format:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
        timeout -s 2 1h ping 96.120.16.121 | 
        ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S |' |
        tee -a ping.log
done
```

expected output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat ping.log
2015-10-30 07:35:29 | PING 96.120.16.121 (96.120.16.121) 56(84) bytes of data.
2015-10-30 07:35:29 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=11.2 ms
2015-10-30 07:35:30 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=9.83 ms
2015-10-30 07:35:31 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=13.0 ms
2015-10-30 07:35:32 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time=17.0 ms
2015-10-30 07:35:33 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=5 ttl=254 time=20.8 ms
5/5 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 9.839/14.399/13.129/20.850 ms
Quit
```

actual:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat ping.log
2015-10-30 07:35:29 | PING 96.120.16.121 (96.120.16.121) 56(84) bytes of data.
2015-10-30 07:35:29 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=11.2 ms
2015-10-30 07:35:30 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=9.83 ms
2015-10-30 07:35:31 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=13.0 ms
2015-10-30 07:35:32 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time=17.0 ms
2015-10-30 07:35:33 | 64 bytes from 96.120.16.121: icmp_seq=5 ttl=254 time=20.8 ms
```

**EDIT**: Ok so I've got the statistics appending to the log file, but whenever I send the `SIGINT` symbol with CTRL+\ ping restarts and the statistics are not logged. I'd like to be able to still pause and see the statistics in terminal without restarting ping if possible

```
[root@localhost ~]# while true; do ping -w 3600 96.120.16.121 | ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S |' | tee -i -a ping.log; done
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do 
        ping -w 3600 96.120.16.121 | 
        ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S |' | 
        tee -i -a ping.log
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `--foreground` option to yout `timeout` command as ping seems to test that
it is being used on a tty to setup signal handling.

---

Or simply stop using `timeout` and ask ping to stop after 60*60 seconds:

```
 ping -w 3600 96.120.16.121
```

---

For your new question, ignore the signals in the rest of your pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -w 3600 96.120.16.121 | 
(    trap '' quit
     ts '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S |' | 
     tee -i -a ping.log
)
```

Comment: `timeout: unrecognized option '--foreground'` sorry i mislabeled debian. im on centos

Comment: I have `timeout --version`  (GNU coreutils) 8.22. Can't you just use `ping -w 3600` and it will stop without needing timeout.

Comment: strange my `timeout --version` is 8.4, but my `man timeout` doesn't have `--foreground`

Comment: I agree with meuh, use the -w option in the ping command.. it will avoid any possible signal issue. Also I recommend not using tee. or if you do turn off stdout buffering. Instead use > to redirect to file, and if you must see stuff on screen start a backgroud tail -f process that monitors the log file for you.

Comment: indeed i got rid of `timeout` and switched to `ping -w`. i would like to see stdout, and i would look into tail that monitors the log file but the next step after this is to grep only the statistics lines to the log while still having pings normal stdout in terminal

Comment: I updated my answer with your new question on how to work with sigquit.

Comment: if i could +1 i would. works exactly how i want... i will make sure to read up on the trap command. thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

By default, *tee* command stop writing and closes the file after receive the signal to stop (a **Ctlr-C**, sent by *timeout* command).

Just add the option *-i* to *tee* and have fun.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
        timeout -s 2 1h ping 96.120.16.121 | 
        ts '%Y-%m-%d~%H:%M:%S' |
        tee -i ping_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S').log
done
```

Comment: `-i` doesnt seem to be working. same result as above. i added the `-a` flag instead of a new log file with a timestamp

Comment: Interesting, I tested before write the comment. Just tried again and worked as before. Please try the output redirector (>) instead of tee command and let me know.

Comment: yes CTRL+\ or sending `SIGINT` restarts ping, but i definitely think youre on to something and my problem has to do with tee and signals

Comment: changing `| tee -i -a ping.log` to `>> ping.log` yielded the same results yet again. the statistics are only saved if ping ends by itself; if i CTRL+\ then ping restarts and the statistics aren't saved

Comment: Guess your different environment are giving different results. I'm running Debian 8.

Comment: i wonder if there is something im missing here... im on centos 6

Answer (score 1):

This runs indefinitely, never restarts ping, ping prints stats periodically (adjust the `sleep` in the following code).  Bash is optional this is /bin/sh compatible.  You can kill this with CTRL-C or SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIQUIT, or SIGTERM.

```
#!/bin/sh

trap 'kill -TERM $! 2>/dev/null; exit' HUP INT QUIT TERM

while true; do
        (
            ping localhost 2>&1 &
            trap "kill -INT $!" HUP INT QUIT TERM
            while true
            do
                sleep 5;
                if ! ps $! > /dev/null || ! kill -QUIT $!
                then break
                fi
            done &
            wait
        ) |
        ts '%Y-%m-%d~%H:%M:%S' |
        tee -i ping_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S').log
done
```

Comment: this seems to have the same effect as removing `timeout` and adding the `-w` flag to `ping` as suggested by @meuh but when i lengthen the desired time, such as 5 to 3600, ping is restarted whenever i send the `SIGINT` signal, i.e. CTRL+\. id like to be able to check the statistics without having ping restarted if possible

Comment: SIGINT and CTRL+\ are different signals.  SIGINT is number 2 and key CTLR+C, SIGQUIT is number 3 and key CTRL+\.  Type `kill -l` to list the signals.  A good reason to use the mnemonics.

Comment: its correctly writing the statistics to the log file with `ping -w`, so i got rid of `timeout`. now the problem is ping restarts whenever i CTRL+\ instead of just outputting the statistics and continuing

Comment: Please post the output of this command: `stty | grep intr`.  What version of unix or linux are you using?

Comment: that command doesnt output anything. im on centos 6: heres my `uname -a`: Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 19:05:58 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Sorry, add `-a` to stty.  I meant to say: `stty -a | grep intr`

Comment: `intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;`